Maximum likelihood and non linear optimization
I have to give a talk about maximum likelihood (statistics) i wanna demonstrate to the class the nonlinear optimization approach for it .Most of the distributions have closed formulas for the expectancy and the variance. So I thought maybe you guys have an idea/example for which I can use numerical optimization method such as gradient ascent to find the wanted estimator.
Thanks!

Logistic distribution, see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461157/when-does-the-mle-of-the-logistic-distribution-exist-and-when-is-it-unique
